# How to enforce office 365 custom "role assignment policy" applied default to all new emails to be created?

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, microsoft-office, mailbox

I have created a `RoleAssignmentPolicy` called `"DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy"` via Exchange `admin center --permissions-- user roles`.

[image]

I would like to apply `"DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy"` default to all new emails accounts to be created.

In gui of Exchange admin center, there seems to be no way to do this. So I did this by longing to office 365 in powershell.

```
Set-RoleAssignmentPolicy DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy -IsDefault
```

The command successfully executed. and when I verify it via `Get-RoleAssignmentPolicy` it says `DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy` is `default`.

```
Get-RoleAssignmentPolicy DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy | select name,isdefault

Name                                   IsDefault
----                                   ---------
DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy      True
```

But when I create a new email and when i go to `recipients --mailboxes-- select user and mailbox features--- Role assignment policy`, still the `default policy` is applied.

[image]

I have to change it manually to `DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy`

What I'm missing here? Please shade a light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run "Set-MailboxPlan" cmdlet to change the default role assignment policy to the customize one.

First, run "get-mailboxplan" to confirm which plan your license is used, as below:

```
Get-MailboxPlan |fl identity,RoleAssignmentPolicy
```

Then, run "Set-MailboxPlan" to change the RoleAssignmentPolciy to the customize one:

```
Set-MailboxPlan -Identity "Plan Name" -RoleAssignmentPolicy "DisabledForwardingRoleAssignmentPolicy"
```

I have test in my exchange online, it works as expected.
[image]

Comment: You are truly a great resource to serverfault. thanks a lot for your time testing it before posting. I was googling and no correct path was found. It worked.